# Google sheets API range issue

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet like this. Those values are just place holders at the moment for my headers

[image]

When I run my PHP script with $range = 'Sheet!F2:L2'; to insert records into the google sheet via API/service account and I only want to start inserting at ROW F for all attempts, it inserts fine on the 1st attempt but all following insertions which then inserts into row 3 and onwards, inserts the data starting at Column 1/A?
[image]

Only when I set my range to F3:L3 and leave row 2 blank does it insert concurrently into the correct columns?

[image]

Code:

```
require '/var/www/html/app/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('My PHP App');
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig('/var/www/html/clients-api/credentials.json');
$sheets = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = '1bo123c1UtdWKV25_312znDO123dDp631238D5qN1123lQ';
$range = 'Sheet1!F2:L2';
$values = [
    [$data->FirstName,$data->LastName,$data->ID,"","",$data->PrimaryNumber,$data->PrimaryEmail]
];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
    'range' => $range,
    'values' => $values
]);
$params = [
    'insertDataOption' => 'INSERT_ROWS',
    'valueInputOption' => "RAW"
];
$result = $sheets->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, $params);

echo '<pre>', var_export($result, true), '</pre>', "\n";
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: code added as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

As you can see [in the official docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values):

> The input range is used to search for existing data and find a "table" within that range.

The data will be correspondingly appended after this "table", starting at the first column of it.

In this case, the first time the data is appended, `F2:L2` doesn't belong to any existing table, since all those cells are empty.

That's not the case in successive times, in which `F2:L2`, already populated, is considered to be part of a table containing the headers in the first row, since there are no blank cells separating `F2:L2` from `A1:L1`. The table that is found, then, when trying to add data to `F3:L3`, corresponds to `A1:L2`. And so it is appending the data starting at column A, since that's where the table starts.

You can check that's the case by examining the `tableRange` from the [API response](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#response-body). In your case, when trying to append `F3:L3`, it will be something like `"tableRange": "Sheet1!A1:L2"`.

#### Solutions:

- One option would be to make the input range refer to row 1 (e.g. `A1`) from the beginning, when appending `F2:L2`, and add empty values at the start of the array `values`:

```
$range = 'Sheet1!A1';
$values = [
    ["","","","","",$data->FirstName,$data->LastName,$data->ID,"","",$data->PrimaryNumber,$data->PrimaryEmail]
];
```

- Another alternative would be to update the input range every time, in order to specify a range that doesn't belong to a "table" (that is to say, successively `F2:L2`, `F3:L3`, `F4:L4`, etc.).

#### Reference:

- [Appending values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values)